# How to change my github page domain (username.github.io/project-name) to just (username.github.io)?

Tags: github, github-pages

This is probably a recurring question, but I could not find the exact answer.

My GitHub page is: https://salehghari.github.io/my_website

And I want to change it to this: https://salehghari.github.io

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rename your repository to salehghari.github.io

Comment: which repository?

Comment: my repository is salehghari.github.io now

Comment: I reviewed and made a pull request, can you merge it to your main branch, the fix will apply. You need to have index.html instead of my_website.html